# Converting a string of pixels into an image python

Tags: python, image, base64

I decododed a base64 encoded picture into a string of pixels with the following line of code:

```
pixelstring = base64.b64decode(imagencoded)
```

The string looks something like this: `b'u\xabZ\x8af\xa0{\xf8\xe9z\x06\xda\xb1\xee\xb8\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\...`

Now I would like to create the original picture with those pixels, my naive approach to this:

```
with open("picture.jpg","wb") as f:
    f.write(pixelstring)
```

however when I try to open the picture the file seems to be corrupt. What am I doing wrong ?

Also I found in the source code of the website I got the base64 encoded picture from the width should be 250 and the hight = 50.

Comment: "String of pixels" isn't PNG, there's another format.

Comment: Was the picture in PNG format before?

Comment: You might try something like `imghdr` to determine the image type before writing as a `png` automatically.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html

Comment: I just realized I wrote png instead of jpg

Comment: I think I know for fact that the picture is jpg since the beginning of the base64 encryption looks like this: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS....

Comment: @Valentino, base64 is an encoding, not an encryption.

Comment: @Olvin Roght that's what I meant, am I only allowed to edit a comment once ?

Comment: @Valentino, you can edit comment only 5 minute after posting it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Convert image to a string of pixel values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719451/python-convert-image-to-a-string-of-pixel-values)

Comment: Not really as it is the other way around and Im not fully getting it.

Comment: Does someone know how the data type  is called ? b'u\xabZ\x8af\xa0{\xf8\xe9z\x06\xda\xb1\xee\xb8\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\...

Comment: Judging by the text `JFIF` I'd guess it's `JPEG File Interchange Format (JFIF)`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some extraneous stuff at the start of your string. JPEG files start with:

```
ff d8 ...
```

So, assuming:

```
str = b'u\xabZ\x8af\xa0{\xf8\xe9z\x06\xda\xb1\xee\xb8\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00...`
```

You need to get the byte position of the start of the JPEG:

```
offset = str.find(b'\xff\xd8')       # You should get "15"
```

and then write:

```
str[offset:]
```

to your file.

Comment: I get 15 as output but the str[offset:] seems to do nothing and I don't really understand how it works. I tried to strip the unwanted part but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try `f.write(pixelstring[offset:])`

Comment: For reference, the "extraneous stuff" is the b64-decoded form of the MIME header for JPEG: `base64.b64decode("data:image/jpeg;base64,")` returns `b'u\xabZ\x8af\xa0{\xf8\xe9z\x06\xda\xb1\xee\xb8'`.